# .htaccess Rewrite /... to /?url=

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite URLs like this: `http://url.maxk.me/abc` to `http://url.maxk.me/?url=abc`, but for some reason it is not working.

Please can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(?:.*)url.maxk\.me/(.*)/?$ url.maxk.me?url=$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't include the domain in the RewriteRule target resource.

It should look like the following if you want the "?url" part to be visible to the user:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://url.maxk.me/?url=$1
```

Otherwise, if you don't want the user to see "?url", it should look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?url=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$   ?url=$1
```